# How to get data from a form and store it in multiple tables in spring mvc hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, model-view-controller

I have these classes:

Article class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "imei")
public class Article {
    @Id
    //@GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "imei1",nullable = false)
    private Long imeiNo;
    @Column(name = "date_added")
    @Temporal(javax.persistence.TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
        private Date addedDate;
    public Article() {      
    }
        public Long getImeiNo() {
        return imeiNo;
    }
    public void setImeiNo(Long imeiNo) {
        this.imeiNo = imeiNo;
    }
        public Date getAddedDate() {
        return addedDate;
    }

    public void setAddedDate(Date addedDate) {
        this.addedDate = addedDate;
    }
```

ArticleDao class:

```
public interface ArticleDao {
// To Save the article detail
public void saveArticle(Article article );

// To get list of all articles
public List<Article> listArticles();
}
```

ArticleDaoImpl Class:

```
@Repository("articleDao")
public class ArticleDaoImpl implements ArticleDao {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    // To Save the article detail
    public void saveArticle(Article article) {
        article.setAddedDate(new Date());

        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().saveOrUpdate(article);
    }

    // To get list of all articles
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public List<Article> listArticles() {       
        return (List<Article>) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(Article.class).list();
    }
}
```

ArticleController:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/articles")
public class ArticleController {

    @Autowired
    private ArticleService articleService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/save", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView saveArticle(@ModelAttribute(" article") Article  article,
            BindingResult result) {
         articleService.addArticle( article);
        return new ModelAndView("redirect:/articles.html");
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView listArticles() {
        Map<String, Object> model = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        model.put("articles",  articleService.listArticles());

        return new ModelAndView("articlesList", model);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/add", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView addArticle(@ModelAttribute("article") Article article,
            BindingResult result) {
        return new ModelAndView("addArticle");
    }

}
```

ArticleService:

```
public interface ArticleService {

public void addArticle(Article article);

public List<Article> listArticles();
}
```

ArticleServiceImpl class:

```
@Service("articleService")
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.SUPPORTS, readOnly = true)
public class ArticleServiceImpl implements ArticleService {

    @Autowired
    private ArticleDao articleDao;

    public ArticleServiceImpl() {
    }

    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, readOnly = false)
    public void addArticle(Article article) {
        articleDao.saveArticle(article);
    }

    public List<Article> listArticles() {
        return articleDao.listArticles();
    }

}
```

Now Created Another class,
OnlyImei.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "onlyimei")
public class OnlyImei {
@Id
    @Column(name = "imei1",nullable = false)
private Long imeiNo;
    public OnlyImei() {     
}
public Long getImeiNo() {
    return imeiNo;
}
      public void setImeiNo(Long imeiNo) {
    this.imeiNo = imeiNo;
}
  }
```

Can you tell me that how to enter values in two tables at one time?  I have to enter imei number in one table and imei and date and time in second table. I have made the second table but I don't know how to enter values at one time in two tables.

Answer (score 1):

Use your service method.  Write to both tables within the transaction.  I don't see a second DAO class, so I'm making one up for this example.

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, readOnly = false)
public void addArticleToBook(Article article, Book book) {
    articleDao.saveArticle(article);
    bookDao.addArticle(article, book.getId());
}
```

The work will be done in the same transaction.

Actually, the above probably isn't best.  Given the way Hibernate supports relationships, you should be able to do this if you have configured Hibernate correctly and used the Spring Hibernate Template:

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, readOnly = false)
public void addArticleToBook(Article article, Long bookId) {
    this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
                       .loadBookById(bookId)
                       .getArticles()
                       .add(article);
}
```

Comment: Sir not able to do it, I have added my new class OnlyImei. Please see what to do

Answer (score 0):

you need create a method in your service, (you may extend your addArticle()method).

You inject two Daos (if there are two) one is `Table1Dao`, another is `Table2Dao`. then in this service method, you do:

```
table1Dao.addxxx(article)
table2Dao.addxxx(article)
```

the parameter is flexible(article, int, array, list, other type), it depends on how did you implement the dao method. and important is, the service method should be executed in one transaction.

Comment: @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, readOnly = false)
 public void addArticle(Article article,OnlyImei onlyImei) {
            
  articleDao.saveArticle(article);
                onlyImeiDao.saveOnlyImei(onlyImei);
 }     Still Not Working

Comment: Changed in my controller also:


 @RequestMapping(value = "/save", method = RequestMethod.POST)
 public ModelAndView saveArticle(@ModelAttribute(" article") Article  article,OnlyImei onlyImei,
   BindingResult result) {
   articleService.addArticle( article,onlyImei);
  return new ModelAndView("redirect:/articles.html");
 }
Still Not Working:

Comment: I have One field Imei1 in both table and in second table i have First field imei1 and second field date/time.
In first table imei1 is primary key and in second table i can have duplicate imei number. So please tell me now how can i add data in two tables, i have performed what you have said but it didnt work.. please tell me